# hide 2 fields only in form from the majority except 2 people

Tags: infopath, office-365, custom-form

I am watching if I can solve my problem with infopath 2013 and I am using the rule Hide control if 'created by' (inputting user) is not Person1 or Person2.

Would it be enough to use the 'type text' and put the full name of Person1?
I need to remove from view the field but I have no problem if it is visible in the All items view of the list. I need to remove it from the new entry form and the edit entry. Is this the best approach?

[image]

It does not work with user id or domain\user id

Since I am on O365 could it be

i:0#.f|membership|name.lastname@tenancy.com
????

Comment: Based on this link - your format comparison should work. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3168272

Comment: You can also look at using the contains function instead of an equal to function

Comment: ok, it worked with contains but I would like to understand the use of substring-after in the example you provided since it did not worked on me

Comment: substring-after or substring-before is a way to get part of the  original string. username() returns just a username without domain but accountID property of the created by returns username with the domain (domain\username). So the domain is extracted from the accountID property and concatenated to username() function output to create a new string which should have the same format domain\username (from accountID property)=domain\username (obtained as a result of string concatenation)

Comment: it didn't work for you because of a number of reasons- one of them is that there is no "\" character in the accountID property on o365.

Comment: getting back to this problem, since my fields to 'hide' based on a 'created by' field are 3 I thought about adding a 'section' and applying the rule to the section containing the 3. I do not get the same success, do you know if sections are treated differently?

Comment: you should be able to apply conditional formatting after selecting the section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have done something similar is to use the username() function which returns the current user ID. You can compare this with the accountID property of the created by field. This article has more details about how to get this working:

http://geekswithblogs.net/ferdous/archive/2013/02/14/infopath-2010-formatting-rules-to-compare-with-current-logged-user.aspx

Comment: I have seen that page. I am confused on why it is needed the domain\username and how to translate that with O365. I have followed the instructions and it does not work.

Comment: see my updated topic